# Button's not working

Tags: java, android, button

Hi guys i am trying to study Android on my own,but stuck with the problem.There are four buttons in a page and if i click one button other button's will not work.This is a code for flashlight,I am trying to make it blink for the required time.Its blinking properly but if i click a button other button won't work.Can anybody give me the suggestion for this problem.Here is the code:

MainActivity.java

```
 Camera camera;
boolean isFlashOn;
boolean hasFlash;
Parameters params;
Button flashOn, flashOff, button1, button2, button3, button4;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkFlashlight();
    getCamera();
    initFlashlightButton();
}

void checkFlashlight() {
    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;
    }
}

private void blink(int time) {

    do {
        turnOnFlash();
        try {
            sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        turnOffFlash();
        try {
            sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        blink(time);
    } while (time <= 10);

}


private void initFlashlightButton() {
    flashOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOn);
    flashOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOff);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    flashOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            turnOnFlash();

        }
    });

    flashOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            turnOffFlash();
        }
    });

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            turnOnFlash();
            blink(1000);
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            turnOnFlash();
            blink(500);
        }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            turnOnFlash();
            blink(300);
        }
    });

    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashOn) {
                turnOffFlash();
            } else {
                turnOnFlash();
            }
            blink(100);
        }
    });
}

private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) return;
        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;
        return;
    }
}

// flash OFF
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) return;

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;
        return;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    turnOffFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (hasFlash)
        turnOnFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="On"
    android:id="@+id/buttonOn"
    android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="62dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Off"
    android:id="@+id/buttonOff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonOn"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonOn"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonOn" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2 Seconds"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonOn"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="4 seconds"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="8 seconds"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="16 Seconds"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonOff"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonOff"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2" />
```

Comment: Make separate method which contains your all button's click listener. Do not  add listener's with view initialization code.

Comment: Are you pressing the buttons one after another without turning the flash off? Then it won't work, because your function `turnOnFlash` only works when the flash is off.

Comment: @Alexander_Winter :If i click ON button it will On,if i click OFF it will OFF but if i click other button say 2 seconds it will blink properly but the remaining buttons will not work.why is that?

Comment: Remove the line `if (!isFlashOn)` from your `turnOnFlash` function and test it again.

Comment: @Alexander_Winter :Ya i removed but still giving the same error.

Comment: @Alexander_Winter :Can you please give me the solution for that?

Comment: @Alexander_Winter :Please check the blink( ); method in my code.Is it correct?

Comment: You'll never leave your `blink`-function with `time <= 10`. With a bigger `time`, your blink will only run once and then leave. You should use `while (true) {}` instead of `do {} while()` and put a `break` into it. Something like `if (breakVal) break;` or `if (breakVal) return;`. Then you should set your `breakVal = true` on button click.

Comment: @Alexander_Winter: Can you please tell me where should i add break?

Comment: @Alexander_Winter: I've added do while loop there ,so can you please tell me where should i add the break statement.

Comment: @Alexander_Winter : if possible can you please mail me the code snippet of blink method at ashishshetty1993@gmail.com

Comment: You should put the blink-function into a background thread. It's possible to lock your screen with an unlimited loop. And remove the blink-call from your blink-function. The break should be in your while-loop in the blink-function.

Comment: @Alexander_Winter :can u please send me the code? i m not getting it...Please

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding `new OnClickListener()` separately to each button, add `implements OnClickListener` to your `Activity` class and add the corresponding void:

```
    @Override
    Public void onClick(View v){
        int id = v.getId();
        switch(id){
        case R.id.yourbutton1:
            //do your job here
            break;
        case R.id.yourbutton2:
            //do your second job here
            break;
        }
    }
```

So instead of adding new OnClickListeners just do this for each button:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: @Oluwantumbi: I have done modification as you said,but still the same error is coming.

Comment: @Oluwantumbi :there are 6 buttons-ON,OFF,2 seconds,4 seconds,8 seconds and 16 seconds.If i click ON and OFF the light will get ON and OFF respectively.If i click 2 seconds flashlight will blink as per the requirements,but when the 2 seconds button is working i can't click any of the other buttons.The flashlight will continuously be blinking i can't even OFF the flashlight.Can you tell me the solution for that?

Comment: @Oluwantumbi :Can you please give me the solution for that?

Comment: @Oluwantumbi :Please check the blink( ); method in my code.Is it correct?

Comment: I posted another answer that addressed your `blink()` method

Answer (score 0):

Your blink method specify `do` - `while` loop which says it should continue blink while time is less than or equal to 10. But i believe this is not what you want to achieve. I believe you want the flash to keep blinking until you press 'stopFlash' button.

For this you have to create a boolean in your activity that lets you know maybe you should stop the flash and use it in your while loop.

Step 1 create a global boolean in your `Activity`:

```
    protected boolean should_continue_flash;
```

Step 2 Use it in your do - while loop

```
private void blink(int time) {

do {
    turnOnFlash();
    try {
        sleep(time);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    turnOffFlash();
    try {
        sleep(time);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    blink(time);
} while (should_continue_flash);
}
```

Step 3 Add code to make your boolean return false so you can stop blinking

Under your `onClick(View v)` method

```
    case R.id.stop_blink_button:
        should_continue_flash = false;
```

Step 4 add this to your button that initiates blink:

```
    should_continue_flash = true;
    blink(your_time_here);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Please look for another way to simulate  blink other than sleep. the sleep will sleep the system and may not be able to listen to your onClick event when asleep. use timer

Comment: How is that? i dont know..can you please send me the code.

Comment: I have posted a new answer that addresses the timer usage

Answer (score 0):

now my code looks like this. please check this.@Oluwatumbi

```
Camera camera;
boolean isFlashOn;
boolean hasFlash;
Parameters params;
Button flashOn, flashOff, button1, button2, button3, button4;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    flashOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOn);
    flashOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOff);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    checkFlashlight();
    getCamera();
    initFlashlightButton();

}


void checkFlashlight() {
    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;
    }
}
  private void blink(int time) {

  do {
      turnOnFlash();
      try {
          sleep(time);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      turnOffFlash();
      try {
          sleep(time);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      blink(time);
  } while (isFlashOn);
}

     private void initFlashlightButton() {


    flashOn.setOnClickListener(this);
    flashOff.setOnClickListener(this);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) return;

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;
        return;
    }
}

// flash OFF
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) return;

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;
        return;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();


    turnOffFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    if (hasFlash)
        turnOnFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    getCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();


    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id=v.getId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.buttonOn:
            turnOnFlash();
            break;
        case R.id.buttonOff:
            isFlashOn=false;
            turnOffFlash();
            break;
        case R.id.button1:
            isFlashOn=true;
            blink(1000);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            isFlashOn=true;
            blink(500);
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            isFlashOn=true;
            blink(300);
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            isFlashOn=true;
            blink(100);
            break;

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity create a `Timer` object so you can use and reuse

```
Timer timer;
```

In your `blink()` method initialize timer and simulate blink like this:

```
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Do the blinking job here
                }

            });
        }

    }, 0, your_time_interval_here);
```

And to stop blink:

```
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();
```

This should work for you

**Documentation here:**

> Open Declaration void java.util.Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long
>   delay, long period)
>
> public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)  Added
>   in API level 1 Schedule a task for repeated fixed-delay execution
>   after a specific delay.
>
> **Parameters** 
>       **task**  the task to schedule.
>       **delay**  amount of time in milliseconds before first execution.
>       **period**  amount of time in milliseconds between subsequent executions.
>
> **Throws** IllegalArgumentException  if delay < 0 or period <= 0. 
>   IllegalStateException  if the Timer has been canceled, or if the task
>   has been scheduled or canceled.

Hope this helps

Comment: its almost working but not as per the requirements...which is that your_time_interval_here?

Comment: now its not getting off..if OFF button is pressed flashlight will be blinking.

Comment: add timer.cancel(); and timer.purge(); to your button you could use if statement incase you have not initialized your timer:: if(timer != null){timer.cancel(); timer.purge();}